# How to stop Java escape coding markup

Tags: java, javascript

I've inherited a java app and I'm new to it.

There's a problem where the XHTML is being escape coded, i.e. `"` is turning into `&quot;` etc which is breaking any new Javascript I add.

Any idea how to stop the page being escape coded?

Comment: Is that a typo u made? Cause `"` should be converted to `&quot;` and not `&quote;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have some HTML (before adding the scripts) & you want to decode the HTML entities, perhaps this could work:

```
var mycode = '<p>&quot;A test string&quot;</p>'; 

var a = document.createElement("div");
a.innerHTML = mycode; 

mycode = a.innerHTML;     // <p>"A test string"</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can unescape it again using [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html)

Comment: id kind of rather try and stop it happening. I'll give that a go if I can't fix it server side